# How do you test if a pair of elements is in a data frame?

Tags: r

Let's say I have this data frame A :

```
A = data.frame(first=c("a", "b","c", "d"), second=c(1, 2, 3, 4))

  first second
1     a      1
2     b      2
3     c      3
4     d      4
```

And I have this data frame B :

```
B = data.frame(first=c("x", "a", "c"), second=c(1, 4, 3))
  first second
1     x      1
2     a      4
3     c      3
```

I want to count the number of times a pair of the data frame B (B$first, B$second) is in the data frame A. The counting part is not the problem, I just can't find the function to determine whether a pair is in a data frame.

The result would be that only c("c",3) is an element of A, so it should be 1. both "a" and 4 are in data frame A, but the couple c("a", 4) does not exist in data frame A, so I don't want to count this. I want the exact match.

I'm looking for a function like %in% that could work for pairs.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
apply(B, 1, function(r, A){ sum(A$first==r[1] & A$second==r[2]) }, A)
```

Basically, what it does is the following: for every row of `B` it applies a function that inspects which elements of `A` are in accordance with row `r` from `B` (part `A$first==r[1] & A$second==r[2]`) and then sums obtained logicals to derive the number of rows in `A` that are in accordance with row `r`.

If you also want grouping it can easily be done with `dplyr` like this

```
cbind(B,tmp) %.% group_by(first,second) %.% summarise(n=max(tmp))
```

where `tmp` is a variable representing the result of the aforementioned `apply`

Comment: Wrong. Editing it now :(

Comment: ^^ was about to comment. I want to check if B elements are in A (not A elements are in B, minor detail) but more specifically I don't want the pair ("a", 4) to be counted and so far your answer is counting it

Comment: Looks like it's doing the job, could you give more detail to what it does so I mark this as answered ? I mean I'll mark it anyway ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative: `rbind` your `data.frame`s together and use `duplicated`.

```
AB <- do.call(rbind, mget(c("A", "B")))
AB$ind <- as.numeric(duplicated(AB))
AB[grep("^B", rownames(AB)), ]
#     first second ind
# B.1     x      1   0
# B.2     a      4   0
# B.3     c      3   1
```

---

You can also probably try to use "digest" to generate a hash for each row, but I'm not sure how efficient this would be:

```
library(digest)
Reduce(function(x, y) y %in% x, 
       lapply(mget(c("A", "B")), function(x) 
         apply(x, 1, digest)))
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Your first solution is actually pretty efficient in terms of computing time

Comment: @T_O, my personal choice among all of these would be my first solution. Just sharing alternatives, that's all :-)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to merge by row, e.g. `mB<-apply(B,1,function(j) paste0(j[1],"_",j[2])` and similarly for `A`  at which point you can loop `mB[j]%in%mA[k]`

Not that I would really recommend doing this :-)

Comment: I've thought of that ; wouldn't there be problems if you don't have injectivity (if you see what I mean) ?

Comment: @T_O  I think it'll work in a double-loop over `j` and `k` .... but as I said, the other answers look much more sensible.

Comment: my point is if A contained the row with elements ("a", "ab") and B contained the row with elements ("aa", "b") it would be a hell of a mess

Comment: @T_O ahhh, of course.  I'll put in a delimiter. Seems I just did this to some other question recently....

Comment: Yup that looks better now ! The delimiter would have to depend on the data used, but I could see "_" work in 99,9% of cases ;)